# Android scrollview performance

Tags: android, performance, optimization, scrollview

Is there any way to improve `ScrollView` performance?

This is just a theoretical question now - I know I can use `ListView`, when I have data which can be easilly placed in a list. But sometimes you just need to use ScrollView...

Everything is ok when you place TextView inside it. But when you place multiple ImageViews with different styles etc. the performance of ScrollView beggins to fade... It looks like the entire view and all its childs are redrawn after moving ScrollView.

Maybe there is a way to turn a drawing cache for it?

EDIT: To be specific - the question is about optimizing scrolling fluency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use Cache Memory for Loading Images. Here is sample for Loading images from Server and store it in Cache and use it..

Check this [Lazy List Sample](http://androidsnips.blogspot.com/2010/08/lazy-loading-of-images-in-list-view-in.html)...

Also Additionally check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899200/android-help-in-adapting-listview-adapter-with-an-imageloader-class/5900058#5900058)..

Comment: Every image I load is loaded in a lazy way (caches etc.) - but the problem (& the question!) is different. I want to know the way to speed up the scrolling experience of ScrollViews (with a lot of content, I have 1-2 fps while scrolling)...