# JSON to retrieve image

Tags: android, json, url

I am using JSON to retrieve user data and I am also getting the image URL but how can I show the image instead of the URL? Currently it only shows the URL from the image.

Here is the code:

```
StringBuilder tweetResultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                //get JSONObject from result
                JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
                //get JSONArray contained within the JSONObject retrieved - "results"
                JSONArray tweetArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("results");
                //loop through each item in the tweet array
                for (int t=0; t<tweetArray.length(); t++) {
                    //each item is a JSONObject
                    JSONObject tweetObject = tweetArray.getJSONObject(t);
                //get the username and text content for each tweet
                tweetResultBuilder.append(tweetObject.getString("from_user")+": ");

           tweetResultBuilder.append(tweetObject.get("profile_image_url")+"\n");

                tweetResultBuilder.append(tweetObject.get("text")+"\n\n");
            }
        }
```

Comment: you can try. this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899200/android-help-in-adapting-listview-adapter-with-an-imageloader-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should download and cashe you image first.
Please read this article [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html), and check [Sample application](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/BitmapFun.zip)

The shorter way to display image from url:

```
new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
                .execute("http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png");




private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a shorter way than the one explained above? As I am getting the URL through JSON so only need to convert it to show it on ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
try {
   ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageUrl).getContent());
   i.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: bad idea ... this will end with NetworkOnMainThreadException ... on Android >= 3.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to download image from the url you are getting.

For that you need to do following things.

```
ImageView my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_imageView);        
        String image_url = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/d/7/e/12570918991185627521Ramiras_Earth_small_icon.svg.med.png";
        Bitmap bm = getImageFromServer(image_url);
        my_image.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

This will call the following function to download image.

```
private Bitmap getImageFromServer(String image_url) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            URL aURL = new URL(image_url);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("DEBUGTAG", "Remtoe Image Exception", e);
        }
        return bm;
    }
```

That's it. Hope this helps you somehow.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried the above code but it didnt show any image, I think it tries to get images from all users and the code only shows for one user.

Comment: @OlympicBeast you can use array of bitmap and store images for multiple users from the loop.

Comment: @OlympicBeast if my given solution helps you to solve your problem then you can accept my answer. Thanks.